# Opencart 2.1 Как передать массив в product.tpl для отображения

Tags: php, opencart

Массив определяется и доступен

```
в model/catalog/product.php
      в  

public function getProduct($product_id) {

array();
```

уже как только не пробывал его определить в controllerи вызвать в tpl - ничего
Подскажите пожлуйста как?

Answer (score 0):

В модели catalog/model/catalog/product.php

```
public function getMyProductData() {
    $my_product_data = array();
    ...
    return $my_product_data;
}
```

В контроллере catalog/controller/product/product.php

```
$data['my_product_data'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getMyProductData();
```

В шаблоне

```
<?php foreach ($my_product_data['value'] as $value) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['text']; ?></td>
              </tr>
<?php } ?>
```